# Bootstrap no aplica los estilos correctamente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estaba haciendo unas pruebas para hacer un formulario con **Bootstrap** y cuando copio y pego el componente `form` no aplica los estilos como aparecen en la página oficial y no encuentro porque.

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS only -->
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName" placeholder="Jane Doe">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Username</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto my-1">
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="autoSizingCheck2">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="autoSizingCheck2">
                Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto my-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Como se ve:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Como debería verse:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ya lo solucione buscando un ejemplo en codesandbox

***Cambiando esto:***

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

***Por esto:***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

Ya vi que el CDN es diferente y que el de la página oficial muestra algo de `npm` pero no sé exactamente que tiene que ver y porque no me funcionaba con ese CDN.

Comment: Siempre que estés en la página de Bootstrap mira la versión de Bootstrap, ya que puede que estés usando una versión distinta del código que estés viendo

Comment: Muchas Gracias @David